Dato NaN en fomulario
tengo un problema con respecto a un formulario, el cual responde en algunos dispositivos
pero por ejemplo en mi telefono o en el telefono de mi jefe me da error con respecto al dato que quiero traer
en general el codigo funciona bien, pero no puedo acceder en uno que otro dispositivo, asi borre la cache en el servidor o en los dispositivos
en algunos dispositivos trae:
{
  "_token": "IkW30XYxjZhu3IKAwXOV0Kko9gAi0xgDQH0zaV3H",
  "payment_confirmation_id": "4429"
}

y en otros
{
  "_token": "IkW30XYxjZhu3IKAwXOV0Kko9gAi0xgDQH0zaV3H",
  "payment_confirmation_id": "NaN"
}

este es el controlador
public function aprobarPago(Request $request)
    {
        $contract = Contract::find($request->input('payment_confirmation_id'));
        $user = User::find($contract->user);

        $contract->pagoConfirmado = 1;
        $contract->activo = 1;
        $contract->status = "active";
        $contract->inicio = date('Y-m-d');
        $contract->fin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));
        $contract->save();

        return redirect('/pagos')->with('success', 'Pago aprobado con exito');
    }

y este es el formulario
<div id="payment-confirm" class="general-popup">
    <div>
        <img src="{{ asset('img/resources/close_icon.svg') }}" class="close">
        <form action="{{ route('confirmarPago') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        @csrf
            <h4>Confirmacion de pago</h4>
            <input id="payment_confirmation_id" type="hidden" name="payment_confirmation_id" value="">
            <span id="payment_confirmation_date"></span>
            <p>Cliente: <span id="payment_confirmation_client"></span></p>
            <p class="highlight">REF: <span id="payment_confirmation_reference"></span></p>
            <span id="payment_confirmation_type"></span>
            <span id="payment_confirmation_bank"></span>
            <h3 id="payment_confirmation_amount"></h3>
            <button id="payment_confirmation_id" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 button-full">{{ __('CONFIRMAR') }}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


En el formulario tienes la misma propiedad id (payment_confirmation_id) en el input que quieres usar en el controlador y también el el botón de enviar, lo cual podría ser la causa de por qué en algunos casos recibes un valor en el controlador y en otros casos no. Viendo tu código, supongo que el valor de ese campo es determinado con JavaScript, ya que el campo es de tipo hidden. Cambia el id del botón y valida nuevamente, si no funciona, entonces verifica la forma en la que le das valor a ese campo (si puedes poner el código en la pregunta mucho mejor, para ayudarte). Saludos.

Si, el problema es que el navegador traduce el payment_confirmation_id por id_pago_confirmación, y por eso sale NaN, lo que hice fue que de esos dispositivos no traduce la pagina y funciona
